# Consuming JAXWS SOAP on spring3.0 way error on jboss 6.0

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws, jboss6.x

I have just upgraded my application from jboss5.0 to jboss 6.0, I am consuming a JAXWS webservices, below are the configuration :

```
<bean id="registerService"   class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
  <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.friendsmirror.register.controller.UserRegisterController" />
  <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="http://127.0.0.1:8080/FriendsMirrorRegisterWS/Register?wsdl" />
  <property name="namespaceUri" value="http://controller.register.friendsmirror.com/" />
  <property name="serviceName" value="UserRegisterControllerImplService" />
  <property name="portName" value="UserRegisterControllerImplPort" />
</bean>
```

while injecting this bean, is throwing exception like:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'registerService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/friendsmirrorBeans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/BeansException
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1444) [:3.1.0.RC2]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518) [:3.1.0.RC2]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455) [:3.1.0.RC2]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [:3.1.0.RC2]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [:3.1.0.RC2]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [:3.1.0.RC2]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [:3.1.0.RC2]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322) [:3.1.0.RC2]
          ... 96 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/BeansException
          at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.configuration.JBossWSBusFactory.getSpringBusFactory(JBossWSBusFactory.java:120) [:3.4.1.GA]
          at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.configuration.JBossWSBusFactory.createBus(JBossWSBusFactory.java:54) [:3.4.1.GA]
          at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:69) [:3.4.1.GA]
          at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57) [:1.0.0.Final]
          at javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:687) [:1.0.0.Final]
          at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.LocalJaxWsServiceFactory.createJaxWsService(LocalJaxWsServiceFactory.java:125) [:3.1.0.RC2]
          at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.prepare(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:334) [:3.1.0.RC2]
          at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:316) [:3.1.0.RC2]
          at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.java:42) [:3.1.0.RC2]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1503) [:3.1.0.RC2]
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1441) [:3.1.0.RC2]
          ... 103 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.BeansException from BaseClassLoader@263b84ee{vfs:///Users/Jayaram/Program/Servers/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/all/conf/jboss-service.xml}
          at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:480) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) [:1.6.0_29]
          ... 114 more 
19:44:27,215 INFO  [config] Initializing Mojarra 2.0.9 (FCS 20120216) for context '/FriendsMirrorWAR'
```

While using the same from stand alone test method or junit, is working absolutly fine, Even its working fine with jboss5.0, I migrated to jboss 6.0 as I required JSF2.0.

Please help me out, Stucked from past 3 Days.

Thanks in advance.

Jayaram

Comment: How do you package your application? What's the location of `spring-beans-xxx.jar`? Is this jar the only one in your classpath?

Comment: Jboss Plugin in Maven, which deployes war package to jboss deploye directory. After a long try the problem got fixed, actually jboss 6.0 come with CXF stack in order to use JAXWS, we need to install JAXWS native stack with proper version(version mappings are in jboss official site)

Comment: [Copying @JayaramPradhan's instructions for installing the JAXWS native stack here, because they were posted as a comment on a question-posted-as-answer that I flagged for deletion.] "Link to check compatibility version: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS-SupportedTargetContainers Down Load Link: http://jboss.org/jbossws/downloads/3x After download please follow the read me guide"